# Why do I get a strangely long opcode when attempting a RIP-relative direct jump with `*...(%rip)` in AT&T assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, att, gnu-assembler

The thing is that I cannot force `gnu as` interpret `jmp` as `short` or `near`, it constantly interprets it as `far`.

For instance, the following code causes `segfault`:

```
int main() {
  asm volatile (
//      ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
//      "jmp lbl%=\n\t"
//      "lbl%=:\n\t"
      "jmp *lbl%=(%%rip)\n\t"
      "lbl%=:\n\t"
//      ".att_syntax\n\t"
      : : : );
  return 0;
}
```

switching to the commented `.intel_syntax` variant, it works perfectly well.

The only difference is that

`jmp lbl%=` in `intel` becomes `eb 00`

while

`jmp *lbl%=(%%rip)` in `att` becomes `ff 25 00 00 00 00`

how to force it in case of `.att_syntax` to interpret it as `short jump`?

Comment: When tagging assembly please also add a tag to identify the architecture.  Is this amd64?

Comment: @TomV, yes, this is amd64

Comment: `ff 25 00 00 00 00` is an indirect jump.  A far jump would be `e9 00 00 00 00`

Comment: Nitpicking: `e9` is still a near jump. Far jump is `ff /5` (or `ea` but that is invalid in 64 bit mode)

Comment: Did you try disassembling the result with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to see what you wrote?  i.e. `FF 25 00 00 00 00    jmp qword ptr [rip]` which is a near absolute indirect jump, using a RIP-relative addressing mode to load a new RIP from memory at `lbl%=:`, i.e. from the 8 bytes following this instruction.  Which likely won't be a canonical 48-bit address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jmp *lbl` does an *indirect* jump -- loading the address from memory at `lbl:` and jumping to that address.  In this case it takes the 8 (code) bytes following this (the function epilog) and treats it as an address to jump to, thus causing a segfault.

For a simple PC relative jump, you want just `jmp lbl` -- att syntax is the same as intel syntax here.  There's no need for `%rip` anything as all direct jumps are PC relative.